# Why I cannot get context value in the server side

Tags: go

I want to sent value from client using Context in the function contextWithValue.

```
func contextWithValue(key int, url string) {
    
        req, err := http.NewRequestWithContext(contextLogger.SetValueX(context.Background()), "get", url, nil)
    
        client := http.Client{}
        resp, _ := client.Do(req)
    
        if err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
        defer resp.Body.Close()
    
        fmt.Println("Response status:", resp.Status)
    
        scanner := bufio.NewScanner(resp.Body)
        for i := 0; scanner.Scan(); i++ {
            fmt.Println(scanner.Text())
        }
        if err := scanner.Err(); err != nil {
            panic(err)
        }
    }
```

But in the server side I cannot get the value from the context using Println function.

```
func Println(ctx context.Context, msg string) {
    id := ctx.Value(RequestId)
    if id == nil {
        log.Println("Could not find value")
        return
    }
    log.Printf("%d   %s", id.(int64), msg)
}
```

What is the wrong here?

Comment: The context isn't part of the request. Go's Context object has nothing to do with HTTP.

Comment: It it more commonly used to pass values between middleware on the server-side. So if you wanted to leverage this mechanism of value-passing, you could put your value in the client-side request - and have a server-side middleware extract that value and update the server-side context.

Comment: You're supposedly confusing contexts with [web forms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/Forms). Contexts indeed allow passing state through all the goroutines whose work logically belongs to handling a particular client request, but the contexts never and in any case somehow "automagically" populated form client-supplied web forms (and cannot _sensibly_ do that).

Answer (score 3):

`context` is not part of HTTP as others have said. From the http [doc](https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#Request.Context) it's stated:

> For outgoing client requests, the context controls cancellation.

> For incoming server requests, the context is canceled when the client's connection closes, the request is canceled (with HTTP/2), or when the ServeHTTP method returns.

So context in term of http client-server communication is only for controlling the calcellation. For client it's to terminate request due to timeout or when context's cancel method invoked whether the request succeed or not from server side. For server it's to listen to client termination/closing connection or specifying server to timeout or stop the process if context timeout due.

You cannot pass values over context since the creation of context only happen on each side of client and server. If you want to pass values, then the only way is to create headers for them.